A variant of Cramer's rule for a homogeneous system of equations
Cramer's rule gives an explicit formula for the solution of $n$ linear equations with $n$ unknowns, represented by the matrix equation:
$$
A x = b
$$
Where $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix and $b$ is an $n$-by-1 vector.
I have a system of $n$ equations in $n+1$ unknowns, of the form:
$$
C x = 0
$$
where $C$ is an $n$-by-$(n+1)$ matrix. I would like to find one non-zero solution of this system (if it exists). Is there a rule, similar to Cramer's rule, that gives an explicit formula to a solution, based on determinants of sub-matrices of $C$?

If your matrix has rank n, you will find a sub matrix with non zero determinant, then you could apply Cramer to this matrix (leaving the extra coordinate to be zero) it’s not a canonical solution but it can give some idea?

Doesn't Cramer's rule work only for non-homogeneous sytstems?

Oh yes, sorry I completely misread

@ErelSegal-Halevi if $C$ has rank $n$, we can take that redundant column on right hand side (by this I mean from the given system of equations, take one variable to the right hand side). Then apply Cramer's rule.
